# UITabBarItem not exactly on bottom

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I've created a custom tabbar but my tabbar isn't exactly on bottom of the screen. I don't know where the mistake can be...but on the bottom of the screen on a height of 2-3 pixels I see the standard tabbar (you can see a highlighted curves on active tabbaritem)...any ideas?

Same on all devices.

Here Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: maybe post some screenshots?

Comment: how did you setup your custom images?

Comment: do u use `selectionIndicatorImage` and `backgroundImage`?

Comment: no I don't thats only 5 images for each tab (5 for active and inactive status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your background image just has the wrong size!? You cannot change the height of the tabbar. Its always 49 points high (in portrait). Means 98px in Retina.

Comment: why not? height is 51 - on another project it has worked...sry for no screenshot, cause its a important project...

Answer (score 0):

Please check in Custom Tabbar Class that you are using if "Y" position and height are okay.
Y position should be 431px for iPhone and for iPad Portrait:975px and Landscape:718px

Also check the images that you are using to be displayed in tabbar have height of 49px for device without retina and 98px for device with retina display

Comment: hi my images in tabbar are 51px, but thats not the problem, height is  not important (its variable). I don't have a custom tabbar class, it's only a method called: (createCustomTabBar) , that's it...

Comment: how do you set images in Tabbar?

Comment: i will try this now:
http://felipecypriano.com/2012/02/27/how-to-customize-uitabbar-on-ios-5/
....